# Check the contents of a div to see if it matches - JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dialog feature on an app I'm making the messages are output in html divs like this:

```
<div class="chat-message error">Message example here</div>
<div class="chat-message error">Message example here</div>
<div class="chat-message error">Latest message</div>
```

I want to check the last message in javascript and see if it's the same as the previous one if it is do nothing if not run my existing dialog code. New chat messages are stored in a variable called `chatBoxMessage`.

I think I need something like this -

```
oldMsg = $('.chat-message').html();
if (oldMsg == chatBoxMessage) {
   //do nothing
} else {
   dialog code
}
```

Comment: You forgot a period to denote the class, it's `$('.chat-message')`

Comment: there is also '.text()' in jquery

Comment: I missed the period their my mistake, but it doesnt fetch the last message in the dom only the first.

Comment: look at this: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-XEDZA/0/1?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery last method :

```
oldMsg = $('.chat-message').last().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [last](https://api.jquery.com/last/) and [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
var lastMessage = $('.chat-message').last();
var previousMessage = lastMessage.prev();

console.log(lastMessage.text() === previousMessage.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `oldMsg` variable holds an array of all the elements with the class `chat-message`. So a better meaningful name for this variable should be `chatMsgs`

```
var chatMsgs = $('.chat-message');
var msgsLen = chatMsgs.length;
```

Now your `oldMsg` would be.

```
var oldMsg = chatMsgs[msgsLen - 1].text(); // Remember array indexes are zero based
```

Or if you think that's too much array manipulation you can use the easier `last()` jQuery method (As pointed out by @Shai). What it does is return the last element from the array of elements. So,

```
var oldMsg = $('.chat-message').last().text();
```

Now happily do your conditioning..

```
if ( oldMsg === chatBoxMessage ) { 
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // dialog code
}
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Thanks for pointing that out! Accounted for.